# strange issue in category edit/update Magento

Tags: magento, categories

Hi i am going through  very strange issue in **magento** , i have **several** categories i magento with child categories , i need to update a category information ,i am able to update the many **categories** but when i try to update the **first** category **under** the **default** category , it didn't work and the **browser** keeps on **loading**  .I have tried to found the issue on google  but nothing was there , in some places it was suggested that it happens due to upgrade but i haven't **upgrade** the magento or any other module .Please suggest me what can be the issue .
Thanks

Comment: Is there any output in your system.log or exception.log? Is the php process still running or did it finish or crash?

Comment: is there any error showing in firebug? for ajax response?

Comment: Can you give me the explanation with picture?

Answer (score 4):

This happens in some cases where the category name contains special characters.

This is for sure a javascript error, otherwise you would have got a response from the server, in this case the you are not getting a response and hence the loading continues. What you could do is check the server response and monitor the firebug / inspect element to get some ideas.

You can check for these javascript elements in the 
/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/category/tree.phtml file.

Comment: no there is no special character in category  http://www.debreiboerderij.nl/wol.html

Answer (score 2):

You should add some more info to the question starting with the Magento version, but follow these steps:

1. Enable error printing in general by adding these lines to your .htaccess

   ```
   SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE 1
   php_value display_errors 1
   ```
2. Enable logging in Magento in System->Confihuration->Developer->Log Settings
3. Do as Keyut suggested and try to update the erroneous category with the console open, monitoring the XHR calls. Check the response of the call invoked after you clicked "Save" for errors.
4. Do as Tobias suggested and check the logs found under var/log in your Magento folder.

By now you should have at least found the error, so you can solve it or ask for further help.

Comment: i have got the  500 Internal Server Error  on ajax request for this and i have check the log als there is nothng in that seems to be